# Issue regarding wrong output with a HackerRank statement on anagrams

Tags: string, stl

For problem statement, please see [this.](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-making-anagrams/problem)

(I have omitted libraries.)

My code works fine (when online judge tests the code) except for this case:

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb

I would love to know why output it expects to be 104 when intersection is zero?

```
std::string string_intersection;

int number_needed(string a, string b) {

int y = a.length();
int z = b.length();

sort(a.begin(), a.end());
sort(b.begin(), b.end());

std::set_intersection(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), std::back_inserter(string_intersection));

int num, x = string_intersection.length();

if(x==0)
    num = 0;

else

num = y + z - 2*x;

return num;


}

    int main(){
    string a;
    cin >> a;
    string b;
    cin >> b;
    cout << number_needed(a, b) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change

```
 if(x==0)
    num = y+z; //as everything needs to be deleted 

else

  num = y + z - 2*x;
```

[image: Check for your self in hacker rank]

Comment: The vital part I was missing. Thanks!